# Export CGPath as JPG or PNG

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

Is it possible to take a path draw in an UIView with CGPath and export it as a PNG?

Comment: Yes. Oh, I suppose you wanted code didn't you?..

Comment: No, to be honest, i just want a pointer to know better. I do not want the fish, i do want to learn how to fish.

Comment: Anyhow, thanks. The yes is something really big. The how is also important, but just to know it is possible is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want a UIImage, not a png file, you can do something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size); 
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapSquare);

//DRAW YOUR PATH HERE

CGContextStrokePath(context);

myUIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[myUIImage retain];  

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: This can however cause blurred images. UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions can be used with its last argument as 0.0 to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do that is to perform the whole drawing again in an image context produced by `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, get an `UIImage` out of it, then save it via the `UIImagePNG/JPEGRepresentation()` functions.

Note that UIView do not "hold" images. You can *rerender* a UIView's layer, but it's a gross violation of MVC (you're using views to store model data!), and it doesn't look clean to me.