# Converting a CGPath to a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgpath

Is there a way of converting a CGPath to a UIImage?

Thanks

Comment: May be a duplicate check out this link, may help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836796/export-cgpath-as-jpg-or-png

Answer (score 4):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
// draw your path here
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: The question was about a `CGPath` not a file system path.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking means that you draw a path in a context and then want that to be converted into an image, then `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` might be what you need.