# Rendering CGPath as a NSImage on Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, nsimage, monomac, cgpath

I have a set of shapes which I generate using`CGPath`. I want to save all those CGPath which I have generated on the disk. Basically I want to render these CGPath as `NSImage`, so that either I can save them on disk or atleast save their `Base64` encoded string.

Here is an example of it done on iOS - [Export CGPath as JPG or PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836796/export-cgpath-as-jpg-or-png?lq=1)

I am trying to do something similar on Mac. I am using `MonoMac` for this and would not mind any Objective-C answers either. I am not even looking for the code, just some hints would be enough.

I have a CGPath as an argument to the method and the method returns NSImage. This method would be called for all the CGPath being generated in another module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after googling and asking people

It needs `CGBitmapContext`

Create an instance of `CGBitmapContext` using `IntPtr.Zero` so that Quartz can allocate memory for you

```
var context = new CGBitmapContext (IntPtr.Zero, width, height,
    8, 4 * column, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB (),
    CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
```

then set the Stroke Color

```
context.SetStrokeColor (new CGColor (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Set line width

```
context.SetLineWidth (2f);
```

Add `CGPath` to this context

```
context.AddPath (cgpath);
```

then stroke the path

```
context.StrokePath ()
```

Get the `CGImage` from the context and create a `NSImage` from it

```
var cgimg = context.ToImage ();
var nsImage = new NSImage (cgimg, new CGSize (cgimg.Width, cgimg.Height));
```